# Why edit text is underlined?

Tags: android, android-edittext

`EditText` is disabled, but still it is underlined. Why, how can I remove underline? What exactly underline means? In iOS same component is `UITextView` but it never underline so the control.

[image]

```
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="305dp"
        android:layout_height="79dp"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText5"
        android:text="Do you know y.."
        android:enabled="false" />
```

Comment: What do u mean by disabled but still underlined?

Comment: Comparing two completly distinct system is not necessary, IOS is not THE standard on UI. Could you provide more information, API used, layout or dynamic View used, well a [mcve].

Comment: But, if you just need it to show text, you could use a [TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> EditText is disabled

Use a `TextView` instead.

> how can I remove underline?

Use a `TextView` instead.

Or, use a different background for the `EditText`, probably. I assume that the `Theme.Material`/`Theme.AppCompat` way of supplying that bracket is via the background, as it was with `Theme` and `Theme.Holo`. I have not changed the background of an `EditText` in years, as usually it is not needed.

> What exactly underline means?

It tells humans that this represents text that they can edit, as opposed to text that they cannot edit.